# How to write transparent Chrome console wrapper?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create simple Chrome console wrapper:

```
function debug() {
    console.log(debug.arguments);
}
```

But it produces slightly different result from native console:

```
console.log("log",1,2,3); //outputs: log 1 2 3
debug("log",1,2,3);       //outputs: ["log", 1, 2, 3]
```

Any idea how to make it behave exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
function debug() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind`:

```
var debug = console.log.bind(console);
```

Comment: `debug()` would have some logic inside (like enable/disable), so it's not 1-to-1.